# reasonml - array or list of tuples

Tags: types, ocaml, reason

I have tuple `type foo = (string, string);`.

1. How to create type - array of `foo` tuples?
2. What is the difference if use array of tuples or list of tuples?
3. How to access array of tuples values?
   JS analog:

   ```
   const foo1 = [1, 2];
   const foo2 = [3, 4];
   const arrayOfFoo =[foo1, foo2];

   console.log(arrayOfFoo[0][0]) // 1
   console.log(arrayOfFoo[1][1]) // 4
   ```

---

UPDATE: I found excelent gitbook

https://kennetpostigo.gitbooks.io/an-introduction-to-reason/content/

```
/* create tuple type*/
type t = (int, int);

/* create array of tuples */
type arrayOfT = array t;

/* create array of tuples */
type listOfT = list t;

/* create list of tuples value */
let values: listOfT = [(0, 1), (2, 3)];

/* get first tuple  */
let firstTyple: t = List.nth values 0;

/* get first tuple values  */
let (f, s) = firstTyple;
```

Is this correct? Ot there is more useful way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `let x: list (int, int) = [(1,2), (3,4)] /* etc */`

2.

- An `Array` fixed-length & mutable, and provides easy random access. It is very similar to a JavaScript list. Use it for things that need random access (read/write) much more than append/pop.
- A `List` is a singly-linked list & is immutable. It will be familiar to folks coming from functional traditions. Use it for things where accessing the first element or pushing/popping from the front is more common than random access.

In practice, I use List for just about everything, but Array for some performance-intensive situations.

3.

Getting the first thing from a list is super common. Often, you want to both do something with the first thing, and then do something with the "rest" of the list. To be thorough, you also want to handle the case where the list is empty. Here's what that looks like:

```
switch (somelist) {
  | [] => Js.log "nothing there" /* what we do if the list is empty */
  | [firstItem, ...rest] => Js.log firstItem /* we have things! */
}
```

If you just want to get the first item, and you're ok w/ your program crashing if it happens to be empty, you can do `List.hd mylist`.

Getting items out of a tuple is like you put, `let (a, b) = sometuple`. If you only care about the first one, you can do `let (a, _) = sometuple` (`_` is a special placeholder that means "I don't care what this is"). For length-2 tuples there are special helper functions `fst` and `snd`, which get the first and second items out for you.